# Reading mail from mbox folder using python

Tags: python, mbox

I want to read mails from a mbox file and do some action based on that. I don't want to write/modify the mbox file but it will be modified by another process (Mostly adding new mails).

I am reading this documentation. http://docs.python.org/library/mailbox.html#mailbox.mbox

But I don't understand the following

1. Should I call lock() before reading the mail? (I am not writing to
   the file)
2. Is there anyway I can get a callback when other process
   (thunderbird) modifies the file?
3. Is the changes in the file reflected in the mbox object? I mean, after I create the mbox object, if a new mail is added to the file, will I access the message using the object? Or should I create a new object again?

PS: I am not allowed to install any plugins of thunderbird:(

Comment: Did you see this sentence in the "Mailbox" doc?  "Each time a message is requested, a new representation (typically a Message instance) is generated based upon the current state of the mailbox."

Comment: @jrennie I think the current state means the state changed via the object and not the file changes. I tried adding a new mail and checking the length, it was the same. When I created a new object again, I could see the addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No need to call `Mailbox.lock()` when you don't modify the mbox. A quote from the documentation of `Mailbox.lock()` (emphasis my own):

   > You should always lock the mailbox before making **any modifications** to
   >   its contents.
2. Notification on file changes is out of the scope of the mailbox module. On Linux systems you can use [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki) to get this functionality.
3. This is also answered in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/mailbox.html#mailbox.Mailbox):

   > The default Mailbox iterator iterates over message representations, not keys as the 
   >   default dictionary iterator does. Moreover, modification of a mailbox during iteration 
   >   is safe and well-defined. Messages added to the mailbox after an iterator is created 
   >   will not be seen by the iterator. Messages removed from the mailbox before the 
   >   iterator yields them will be silently skipped, though using a key from an iterator 
   >   may result in > a KeyError exception if the corresponding message is subsequently 
   >   removed.

   In short, you need to create a new `Mailbox` instance, after the mbox file has changed.